# Generating data based on condition using R code

Tags: r, generated

Suppose I want to generate X and Y condition of previous object of X and probability (F). My algorithm: In a particular day one individual have status 1/0. If status 0 then status of the next day will be `rbinom(1,1,0.5)`; if status 1 then staus of the next day will be `rbinom(1,1,F[this day])`. Here I am wanted to generate this data for N individuals and d days.

My code:

```
N <- 10 # number of individual
d <- 10 # days
F <- c(0.9,0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4) # Probabilities

    for(j in 1:N){
        x <- NULL
        x[1] <- rbinom(1,1,0.5)
        y <- NULL
        y[1] <- ifelse(x[1]==1, 1, 0)
        for(i in 2:d){ 
            if(x[i-1]==0)
            {
            y[i] <- x[i-1]
            x[i] <- rbinom(1,1,0.05)
            }
            if(x[i-1]==1) 
            {
            y[i] <- y[i-1]+x[i-1]
            x[i] <- rbinom(1,1,F[y[i]]) 
            }
        }

    }
```

This code produces data like,

```
   > x
     [1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
    > y
     [1] 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

But I want to generate X and Y like this:

```
 > x
 [1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
> y
 [1] 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

I don't find out which part of the code is wrong. Could anybody help?

Comment: If you are using `rbinom`, then the output will be to some extent .... "random". So the question becomes: in what sense is the output you are getting not "like" the output you are expecting? You have not (yet) explained what this process is supposed to be doing and have only produced code that you think is erroneous so there seems little point in trying to meld with "Fortran-mind" in order to produce efficient R code.

Comment: Thanks. I am modified my question above.

Comment: The first thing to realize is that the outer loop is doing this process 10 times but is only leaving the last one to be examined. You could remove the outer loop and nothing should appear to change. I will make a few changes to the code and you can see if you might really already be doing what you intended.

Comment: Could you please post the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop can be removed and then you can store the output at each iteration using the `replicate` function. I'm also extending the process to 20 steps to see if you can see instances where you get two "events".

```
N <- 10 
d <- 20
F <- c(0.9,0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4) 
   replicate(10,{     x <- NULL
        x[1] <- rbinom(1,1,0.5)
        y <- NULL
        y[1] <- ifelse(x[1]==1, 1, 0)
        for(i in 2:d){ 
            if(x[i-1]==0)
            {
            y[i] <- x[i-1]
            x[i] <- rbinom(1,1,0.05)
            }
            if(x[i-1]==1) 
            {
            y[i] <- y[i-1]+x[i-1]
            x[i] <- rbinom(1,1,F[y[i]]) 
            }
        }
      return(rbind(x,y)) } )
```

After a couple of runs I do see one where you get what (I think) you want, namely two series of positive values in x and y. It happened to be the seventh instance in that run of 10:

```
, , 7

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
x    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0
y    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     2     3     0     0     0     1     2     3     4     0
```

You never described in natural language what was not satisfying about your current output so I suppose this is still just guesswork. I also think you should assign the results of your simulations to an object so you can examine later programmatically when N becomes high enough that it's not feasible to review by eye.

```
res <- replicate( 1000, { code block here } )
```

Comment: But this is not my required one. For example, in column 9 to 12 observation of x: 1, 1, 1, 0 and y: 0, 1, 2, 3. But I want like x: 1, 1, 1, 0 and y: 1, 2, 3, 0.